# Convergence of certain L-series

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, l-functions

Suppose $|a_{n}| \leq 1$ completely multiplicative function assuming real values. 
Suppose further that, 
$
L(s)=\sum_{n} \frac{a_{n}}{n^s}
$
may be continued analytically to the left of $s=1$ a bit (say $Re(s)>1-\epsilon$)

((This is to be done by writing
$L(s)=exp(\sum_{p} \frac{a_{p}}{p^s})G(s)$, where $G(s)$ is a harmless function and by partial summation together with the bound, $\sum_{p \leq x} a_{p} \ll x^{1-\epsilon}$ )) .
Can we conclude that $L(s)$ converges for $Re(s)>1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ ?

Regards.

Comment: Do you have an actual example in mind, or are you trying to find another proof for a known example?

Comment: As a matter of the fact: I know that how to extend the series  $\sum_{p } \frac{a_{p}}{p^s}$, to the left of s=1 and make sure that the "prime" series converges there. The question turns out to be how one can conclude conclude results on convergence of $\sum \frac{a_{n}}{n^s} $?

Comment: Are you looking at something that is not a Dirichlet $L$-function? Also, when you say you know how to "extend" the series I am not sure what you mean: do you know the series you're looking at has an analytic continuation a little to the left of 1, or more precisely do you know that the series you are looking at converges a little to the left of 1?

Comment: Of course I meant extending analytically to the left of s=1. Dirichlet L-series is one of such examples.

Comment: @user4486 You presumably know very well, but I say it just in case, that when the coefficients $a_n$ are positive this is true, by a result of Landau (which is in chapter V of Serre's course in arithmetic). I believe it is false without the positivity hypothesis, but don't have a counter-example at hand. Good question.

Comment: @user4486: I had asked if you are looking at something that is not a Dirichlet $L$-function. Could you tell us exactly what your example is? Without the condition that the coefficients are bounded there is an easy counterexample: let $\chi$ be a nontrivial quadratic character and set $a_n = \chi(n)n$.  Then $L(s) = L(s-1,\chi)$, which extends analytically to the whole plane but converges nowhere on the half-plane ${\rm Re}(s) < 1$ since it would imply convergence of $L(1) = \sum \chi(n)$.

Comment: As Joël said, this is related to Landau's theorem. I suggest checking Montgomery and Vaughan's book: in the section on Landau's theorem, there almost surely will be an exercise giving a counterexample in the non-positive case.

Comment: If your analytic continuation of $L$ comes with some kind of polynomial bounds for $|L(s)|$ in the region Re$(s)>1-\delta$, then you could shift contours and prove that $\sum_{n\le x} a(n) \ll x^{1-c\delta}$ for some constant $c>0$ (depending on your polynomial type bound for $L(s)$).  That'll give the desired convergence to the right of $1-c\delta$.

Comment: @Lucia,KConrad  I wrote the way that I obtained analytic continuation of $L(s)$. In fact my starting point is $\sum_{p \leq x} a_{p}$, using this I want to pass to the convergence of the series $L(s)$ to a larger half-plane.